# Org-mode - let it open .org files unfolded

Tags: org-mode

I would like to know if it is possible for org-mode to open its org files in unfolded state, and possibly with specified level (e.g no more than *** headlines) and possibly with option to fold/unfold bodies as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the `#+STARTUP` directive for per-file default view settings:

- https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html#In_002dbuffer-Settings
- https://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-Cycling.html#Visibility-Cycling

You can use `org-customize` to set global defaults, or even use the `VISIBILITY` property inside a heading to affect a particular sub-tree.

Allowed values include: overview, content, showall, showeverything.

I don't recall an option for specifying a global N levels of visibility (you can put together some elisp for this); anyhow this is quite easy to do on the keyboard (e.g. `M-3 S-TAB` will display all headings up to level 3).

Answer (score 4):

In your dot emacs:-

```
(setq org-startup-folded "showall")
```

Answer (score 2):

Start-up folding is controlled by the `org-startup-folded` variable. It can also be set by placing:

```
#+STARTUP: fold
#+STARTUP: nofold
#+STARTUP: content
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

any where in the buffer.

Comment: I want to do this without changing the org file.  I want all of the org files to open showing everything.  Is there no magic for the init.el file to make this happen, always?